# This sentence from the SAT seems to have a subject-verb disagreement (but it isn't)

Tags: verbs

From the SAT:

> A poetic form congenial to Robert Downing was the dramatic monologue, which **let** him explore a character's mind without simplifications demanded by stage productions.

The subject doing the **let** is the dramatic monologue, which is singular. So why would it not be **lets**?

Another question is what is the verb **explore**? Is it an infinitive or gerund? Because I don't think there is anyone doing the action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, *let* is the past tense of the verb *let,* and means *allowed. Lets (allows)* would be the present-tense form.

It's past tense because of the verb *was:* the sentence describes a past situation.

> The dramatic monologue **was** congenial to Downing. It **allowed** him to explore a character's mind.

*Explore* is a simple infinitive. *Let* does not permit infinitives to take the particle *to,* which *allow* requires.